# Should this question about protests at US airports be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

[This question about Hong Kong airport protests happening in the US](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/43688/18862) ([cached](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qwFrJRs0AkQJ:https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/43688/what-if-hong-kong-airport-protest-happened-in-the-us)) was deleted by the community user, I assume because the author's account was removed / deleted.

The question was closed and had three pending reopen votes at the time of deletion. It also had an answer (by me), which had a few upvotes and was accepted. The question is a bit speculative, but only to the extent that other well-received questions have been, like these [*what would happen if ...?* questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=would+happen+if).

I first cast an undelete vote, which was recorded but doesn't seem to show up in the [delete vote overview of the 10K mod tools](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tools). Neither did the deletion show up under *recent occurrences*, I'm not sure why that is.

I then flagged a moderator because I thought the question had been deleted erroneously without the possibility of the community to provide a check through the normal channels (i.e. 10K tools on deletions). Unfortunately, that flag was denied without an explanation.

Therefore, my question is if this question should be undeleted or not and why.

Somewhat tangentially I'm also wondering why neither the deletion, not my undelete vote show up in the 10K tools. But I guess that's probably due to the community user doing the deleting and better suited for the main meta site.

Comment: The question was deleted [when the user was deleted](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/43688/timeline#history_08eed2b7-8871-4ddf-9dd7-5a8f3f6da837)

Comment: Open questions with positively-scored answers are ordinarily excluded from automatic deletion upon user deletion, but if the question is closed, it is still deleted if it's negatively-scored.

Answer (score 1):

This question isn't of much quality. Your (accepted) answer to it was basically "we can only speculate". Frankly leaving it deleted would have been not much worse than what we have now; where we have a *closed* question with the answer "we can only speculate"...

Comment: I think it's a bit more than saying we can only speculate. Such question are asked quite often and except for some pointers there's no conclusive answer. If you (and others?) really think such questions should be closed (as POB?) rather than providing some considerations in a non-conclusive answer than that's probably the subject of a different (new?) meta discussion. I think it's fine to have them because it may not always be clear (for potential askers and others too) whether there is a conclusive answer or not beforehand.